# Selecting correct method of struct based on input type

Tags: c++

I'd like to have a template function that accepts an object of type T from which a method in a correct class will be chosen and run.
Something like this,

```
struct TypeX
{};
struct TypeY
{};

struct X
{
    void Do(TypeX &r){}
};
struct Y
{
    void Do (TypeY & r){}
};  

template<typename T>
void Do(T& r)
{
   // if(T==TypeX) call X::Do(r)    
}
```

And my solution becomes either

```
template<class V, typename T>
void Do(T& r)
{
   V::Do(r);    
}
```

or

```
template<class B, typename T>
void Do(B*p, T& r)
{
   p->Do(r);    
}
```

However it looks flawed, e.g
in my `main.cpp`, I have to create a `B` pointer
either as
`B*p=new X;`
or `B*p=new Y`
and I don't like dynamic allocation or introducing `B` type into `main` at all. I only want my function to accept one parameter of type `T` of either `TypeX` or `TypeY` then it has to distinguish the input to call the corresponding method from `X` or `Y`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use *dynamic polymorphism* instead. You can achieve this by means of *virtual functions* and *inheritance*. First, define a class `Base` which serves as an *abstract class*:

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual void Do() = 0;
};
```

Both `X` and `Y` will derive from this class `Base`. Both `X`and `Y` must implement the `Do()` member function, otherwise they cannot be instantiated:

```
struct X: public Base {
   // define your Do() function member for X
   virtual void Do() override {
      ...
   }
};

struct Y: public Base{
   // define your Do() function member for Y
   virtual void Do() override {
      ...
   }
};
```

You don't need dynamic allocation at all:

```
struct X x;
struct Y y;

Base *p = &x //or &y
```

All you have to do is to select the proper `struct` (i.e.: either `X` or `Y`) to instantiate based on the input type, then assign the address of that object to a pointer to `Base` and then call `Do()`:

```
Base *p = // <-- address of struct X or struct Y object
p->Do();
```

The proper `Do()` member function of will be called based on the type of the object you instantiated: either `struct X` or `struct Y`.

Answer (score 1):

Since *C++17* you could use `if constexpr`:

```
template<typename T>
void Do(T& r)
{
   if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, TypeX>) {
       X::Do(r);
   } else {
       Y::Do(r);
   }
}
```

[**Example**](https://godbolt.org/g/tPCzSW)

before that you could experiment with tag dispatching instead but it requires more code to write.